# How to disable all graphQL endpoints with a configuration?

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql

Using this dependency,

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.graphql</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-graphql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Is there any configuration that can disable all GraphQL endpoints / controllers? I was suggested to look for something like `spring.graphql.enabled` but no luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one endpoint in GraphQL and that is `www.server.com/graphql`. If you want to secure access to it, you can update the spring security configuration in this way.

```
        http.authorizeHttpRequests { auth ->
            auth.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/graphql")
                .authenticated()
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/graphql*")
                .authenticated()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
        }
```

When using GraphQL in production, you may want to disable introspection query because introspection is the ability to query which resources are available in the current API schema. For some scenarios, it can be counted as a security issue. Here show you can disable `introspection query` in Spring GraphQL.

```
    @Bean
    fun wiring(): RuntimeWiringConfigurer {
        return RuntimeWiringConfigurer { builder ->
            builder.fieldVisibility(NoIntrospectionGraphqlFieldVisibility.NO_INTROSPECTION_FIELD_VISIBILITY)
        }
    }
```